# How can I center the logo and center the menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let's take a look at my first and simple website. I have made the website from the tutorial, but I want to change a few things:

First: the logo "Bukowski" I want to have at center on the white space and (when I shorten the screen and making it bigger all the time at center) ,

Second: I want to have the menu at center, not to the left.

Third: When I make the screen smaller than 996px the black block appears and goes up. I want my menu to collapse below 996px normally but without the black block goes up.

And the forth and last: Take a look please at html code and please tell me what should I add to the
head tags I mead meta-ta

```css
@font-face {
  src: url(mistral.ttf);
  font-family: mistral;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.logo2 {
  font-family: mistral;
  font-size: 100px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 0px 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background: #111;
  z-index: 1000;
}

header .logo {
  font-family: 'mistral';
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

header ul {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

header ul li {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}

header ul li a {
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

header ul li a:hover,
header ul li a.active {
  background-color: #205aff;
}

.toggle {
  display: none;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 120px 50px 100px;
  text-align: justify;
}

.nag {
  text-align: center;
}

section img {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

section h2 {
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

section p {
  font-size: 18px;
}

section a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #111;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

section:nth-child(odd) {
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #111;
  color: #fff;
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  section h2 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  section {
    padding: 100px 50px 50px;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
  }
  section img {
    margin: 50px 0 0;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  header ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: -100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100vh - 80px);
    padding: 50px 100px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: auto;
    transition: 0.9s;
    background: #111;
    flex-direction: column;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  header.active ul {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 80px;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  header ul li a {
    margin: 5px 0;
    font-size: 24px;
  }
  .toggle {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .toggle:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 0 #fff;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }
  .toggle:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 4px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }
  header.active .toggle:before {
    top: 14px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 #fff;
  }
  header.active .toggle:after {
    top: 14px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
}

.nag2 {
  font-family: 'mistral';
  font-size: 150px;
  margin-left: px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.nag h2 {
  letter-spacing: 30px;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Bukowski</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header id="header">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#home" class="active" onclick="toggle()">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about" onclick="toggle()">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#services" onclick="toggle()">Service</a></li>
      <li><a href="#portfolio" onclick="toggle()">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#team" onclick="toggle()">Team</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact" onclick="toggle()">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="toggle" onclick="toggle()"></div>
  </header>
  <section id="home">
    <div>
      <div class="nag">
        <div class="nag2">Bukowski</div>
        <h2>LEATHER WEAR</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <img src="fota2.jpg">
  </section>
  <section id="about">
    <div>
      <h2>About Us</h2>
      <p>Jesteśmy polską firmą odzieżową, zajmującą się dystrybucją, produkcją, oraz projektowaniem odzieży skórzanej i kożuchów . Nasza marka istnieje na rynku od 1992 roku. Firma Bukowski to polska marka dedykowana ludziom ceniącym sobie niebanalny styl,
        komfort i wygodę. Oferowane przez nas kolekcje to nawiązanie do nowoczesności zgodne z aktualnymi trendami. Doświadczenie sięgające niemal 30 lat to doskonała gwarancja wysokiej jakości produktów oraz zaufania klienów. Serdecznie zapraszamy do
        nabywania produktów w naszych punktach sprzedaży.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="services">
    <div>
      <h2>Our Service</h2>
      <p>Wychodząc także naprzeciw oczekiwaniom naszych klientów, poza standardowym asortymentem oferujemy szycie na miarę. W naszych punktach sprzedaży posiadamy wykwalifikowany personel, który może pobrać wymiary od indywidualych klienów. Dzięki temu u
        nas każdy klient może znaleźć coś dla siebie. Również oferujemy pomoc w zakresie skracania, zwężania, renowacji bądź wymiany poszczególnych elementów w produktach u nas zakupionych. Dzięki temu możemy przedłużyć użyteczność i żywotność naszych
        produktów dzięki czemu możecie Państwo cieszych się naszyi produktami przez długie lata.
      </p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="portfolio">
    <div>
      <h2>Our Recent Work</h2>
      <p>Od niemal 30 lat obecności na rynku, nieustannie dokładaliśmy wszelkich starań, aby nasze produkty cechowała najwyższa jakość. Ostatnio jeszcze bardziej poszerzyliśmy nasz asortyment o nowe produkty. Posiadamy ponad sto różnych wzorów w różnych
        kolorach i nieustannie pracujemy nad poszerzeniem naszej oferty. W ostatnich latach nasz asortyment zwiąkszył się kilkukrotnie. </p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="team">
    <div>
      <h2>Our Expert</h2>
      <p>Posiadamy wysoce wykwalifikowaną kadrę pracowniczą, która jest jednym z podstawowych gwarantów uzyskania efektywnych wyników naszej firmy. W pierwszej kolejności zapewniamy naszym pracownikom odpowiedni poziom przygotowania w zakresie krojenia,
        szycia, a także sprzedaży finalnych produktów w naszych punktach sprzedaży. Nasza kadra jest do Państwa dyspozycji oraz dołoży wszelkich starań, aby nasi klienci mogli cieszyć się z nabytych u nas produktów przez długie lata. Wieloletnie doświadczenie,
        które nabyliśmy przez dziesiątki lat istnienia na rynku, pomaga nam wyjść naprzeciw potrzebom najbardziej wymagających klientów.
      </p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="contact">
    <div>
      <h2>Contact Us</h2>
      <p>
        Siedziba firmy: <br><br> Rogoźnik os. Za Torem 20a<br> 34-471 Ludźmierz<br><br> tel 48 18 265 56 53<br> tel./fax: 48 18 265 53 05<br> kom. 48 603 607 832<br> kom. 48 604 971 789<br> kom. 48 695 069 380<br><br> e-mail: bukowski@interia.eu


      </p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle() {
      var header = document.getElementById("header");
      header.classList.toggle('active');
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This looks like a custom order. It doesn't look like a problem it looks like a job!

Comment: It's also 4 questions

Comment: I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: It's not a job because its my parents company I don't take any money form that:) I managed to fix 3 problems but still don't know how to fix number 3 problem
When I make the screen smaller than 996px the black block appears and goes up. I want my menu to collapse below 996px normally but without the black block goes up.